# Spring boot (with security) behind Kong reverse proxy not working correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, kong

I have a spring boot service with security over Keycloak.
The Service is working fine: http://localhost:8080/api/resource (is restricted) and only after authentication via keycloak accessible.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/open/*").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Now i am using Kong as reverse proxy for the wolrd outside: The entry for that is (for instance): https://gateway.example.com/customer which redirects to http://localhost:8080

After calling https://gateway.example.com/customer/api/resource, something goes wrong, instead to call  https://gateway.example.com/customer/sso/login it calls https://gateway.example.com/sso/login and so i get "404 Not Found".

It seems that the security part remove or let's say ignore "customer" in the location.

There is a possibility to correct the location?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a route matching by path and you won't that this will be stripped you need to set  `strip_path` to `true`

Check the [documentation](https://getkong.org/docs/0.13.x/admin-api/#route-object).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but just had this happen. In application.properties, try using this setting:

```
server.use-forward-headers=true
```

That will tell spring boot to forward requests relative to the proxy, not your app.